# adding multiple fetch request inside a method using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch

Wondering how do i chain multiple fetch requests inside of a method. I want these to run right after eachother. They all will go to different routes, but guess they need to delay a bit so it doesn't conflict?. Not familiar with how to do this with vuejs and fetch but done similar using coroutines .

```js
submit: function() {
  let myTitle = "myTitle"
  let myKolReferrer = "foo"
  let myChefs="chef jacob"
  let myDog="doggy"
  
  fetch("", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"96\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"96\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
    },
    "referrer": "",
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "body": `title=${myTitle}&kol_referrer=${myKolReferrer}`,
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });
  fetch("", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"96\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"96\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
    },
    "referrer": "",
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "body": `title=${doggy}&kol_referrer=${myKolReferrer}`,
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });
  fetch("", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"96\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"96\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
    },
    "referrer": "",
    "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
    "body": `title=${myChefs}&kol_referrer=${myKolReferrer}`,
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<button v-on:click="submit()">Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Most likely you would use promises.  And when they resolve call remaining requests.

Comment: Try taking a look at async/await, you will need to make your method async

Comment: There are two things confusing me first you they will run after each other - so will these api calls start after one ends or will they work simultaneously... second they will go to different routes

Answer (score 0):

Async & Await will made the trick

```
async submit() {
   const request1 = '...';
   const request2 = '...';
   const response1 = await fetch(request1).then(response => response.data)
   const response2 = await fetch(request2).then(response => response.data)
}
```

However, it's highly recommended to request all together for optimize by using

`Promise.all([...])`

Remember to set `catch` as well in each fetch, for managing possible endpoint errors

Comment: what goes in const request1 and const request2?